# Is it possible to delete objects in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of `Account` objects stored in `AccountList`. Now I want to remove a `Account` so, that I also can not add it to the list again if I still have that object - meaning the object shouldn't exist at all anymore.

In my Code I go through the `AccountList` list and search for the `Account` with the matching `id`. Then, when the matching `Account` was found, that `Account` should be deleted (and therefore also be removed from `AccountList`).

```
public bool Delete_Account(int id)
{
    foreach (var account in AccountList)
    {
        if (account.id == id)
        {
            //delete Account object here
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this possible in C# and if not, how would I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: `return AccountList.RemoveAll(item => item.id == id) > 0;` if `AccountList` is of type `List<T>`

Comment: what do you mean by _"delete an object"_ ? Remove it from `AccountList` ?

Comment: How's `account` from `AccountList` related to `objekt`?

Comment: No I dont want to remove the object out of the list, I want to delete the object. It shouldn't exist anymore, it shouldn't be in the AccountList and I should also not be able to add it to the list. I can create a object, why can't I delete it then?

Comment: You cant remove item from list while iterating it's elements. You can try find the suitable index of your account id and the use AccountList.Remove(index). If no suitable index found (index ==-1) you can return false.

Comment: You don't delete objects in C#. You can stop *referencing* them (such as by removing the reference contained in the list and any other variables and lists) and, at some future point in time they may be cleaned up.

Comment: The Garbage Collector will _eventually_ free the memory occupied by a previously created object, *if* that object is no longer referenced anywhere. So basically you "delete" it by making sure, the object is not used (i.e. referenced) anywhere anymore.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever one can't "*delete*" an object, but one can "*dispose*" an object if it implements `IDisposable`, which may be what OP is looking for

Comment: @Rafalon how do I dispose a object then? sounds like it could work.

Comment: @speyck you don't, unless the object makes use of an _unmanaged resource_, for example a file handle requested from the operating system, that the garbage collector does not track. Then and only then, you need to synchronise the freeing of that resource with the freeing of the object by the garbage collector, which is what IDisposable is for. _You do not delete objects yourself in C#_. This question is seeming like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You might want to read about [automatic memory management](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/automatic-memory-management) chances are, you will never need to worry about it and never need to implement IDisposable. Just let the GC do it's job, it does it pretty well. Only if you're very sure you're working with unmanaged resources, you might want to [implement IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

Comment: If you really had to delete a managed object, my understanding is that you can immediately force the garbage collection with an explicit call to GC as in: myObject = null; GC.Collect();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One does not simply delete an object in `C#`.

`C#` is a **managed** language, which means that all memory allocation/freeing stuff is moved from programer scope. When you `var x = new object();` - .net CLR (Common Language Runtime) allocates necessary memory and starts tracking references to this memory.

When references count went down to 0 (i.e. when you return from method and variable `x` disappears from your scope, or when you do `x = null;`) - this memory is marked for deletion and sometime after (no guarantees when, maybe on next millisecond, maybe on next month) a special service called GC (Garbage Collector) will finally free this memory.

So, just remove this object from list, and if it is not stored in any other list/variable, its allocated memory will be freed in sometime (again, no one knows when exactly).

Things goes a lot more interesting, when you start working with **unmanaged** resources (like OS window handles), but this is another story.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be ok:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var accounts = new List<Account>();

        //Feed list

        var done = DeleteAccount(accounts, 1);

        if (done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account deleted!");
        }
    }

    public static bool DeleteAccount(List<Account> accounts, int id)
    {
        var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if(account is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        accounts.Remove(account);
        return true;
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```